# Django model method, referring to other model via FK

Tags: django, methods, models

My model is like so:

```
class PlayerProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team)
    is_captain = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.get_username()

class Game(models.Model):
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team)
    game_time = models.DateTimeField()
    location = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.team.name + ' ' + unicode(self.game_time)

class GameStatus(models.Model):
    game = models.ForeignKey(Game, default=None, null=True)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, default=None, null=True)
    player = models.ForeignKey(PlayerProfile, default=None, null=True)
    game_status = models.CharField(max_length=1)
```

Is it possible to write a method in PlayerProfile that can access the GameStatus model so that I can get a game_status property, if one exists?

Comment: Any luck with this yet? I think you're definitely on the right track.

Comment: I tried your latest update but it's not giving me what I'm aiming for. That latest code iterates through all the players fine (which I want) but the inner loop just iterates through every gamestatus, I only want the inner loop to iterate through that particular player and game.id.. I'll keep trying, thanks though. BTW, I can't upvote until I get a certain reputation or something

Comment: Ahh, I understand now. Check out the edit to my question for the proper lookup. As an FYI, __accepting__ is not the same as __upvoting__. You can always _accept_ an answer to a question you've asked_regardless_ of reputation.

Answer (score 0):

No need to write a method on `PlayerProfile`.

You can used the built-in relationship manager to look this up via the parent `PlayerProfile`, provided you know which `GameStatus` belonging to the `PlayerProfile` you need to access:

```
# look up first player returned from the PlayerProfile model manager
player_profile_1 = PlayerProfile.objects.all()[0]

# look up first game status associated with the first player profile, 
# then access the game_status attribute
game_status_1 = player_profile_1.gamestatus_set.all()[0].game_status
```

**UPDATE**:

If you can access the `game_status` of a game from within a loop like this:

```
{% for playerprofile in game.team.playerprofile_set.all %}
    {% for game_status in playerprofile.gamestatus_set.get(game_id=game.id) %}
        {{ game_status.game_status }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: in those examples, how do I specify a game (for the GameStatus)? Also, where do I put these? in the view? template?

Comment: How do you _want_ to specify the game? By what attribute do you want to look a game up? You'll presumably want to use this in the view, since it's business logic.

Comment: with a PK, so basically by providing a game_id...

also, out of curiosity to answer the original question, would it be possible to do in a method?

edit: this is essentially a left outer join to gamestatus

Comment: You're asking a lot of stuff at once. Let's go step by step. Here's a question: if you already know the id of the game, why do you need to access it via the parent? Why not look it up directly?

Comment: because in my template I'm using a class-based view based on the 'game' model so in that template I have access to the game_id and I'm doing a {% for playerprofile in game.team.playerprofile_set.all %} loop... PS - I am a complete Django n00b

Comment: Please post your `Game` model.

Comment: class Game(models.Model):
 team = models.ForeignKey(Team)
 game_time = models.DateTimeField()
 location = models.CharField(max_length=100)
 def __unicode__(self):
     return self.team.name + ' ' + unicode(self.game_time)

Comment: Please post it to your __question__ for the benefit of other readers.

Comment: zeantsoi, for your solution, it only pulls the one status for every unique player in the loop. How do I pass in a playerprofile to {{ game.gamestatus_set.all.0.game_status }}?

Comment: You should be able to evince the answer from the code you've already written it. You'd accomplish it in the precise manner that you're looping through each `PlayerProfile` associated with a `Game`. See my updated code.